# How to retrieve dates that have corresponding entries in table using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Let's say I have a "posts" table with the default "created_at" attribute.
I need to get something like the last 4 unique dates in which posts have been written.

Is there an efficient way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select 4 unique dates like following:
1. For MySQL

```
Post.select("Date(created_at) as date").order("created_at desc").uniq.limit(4)
```

2. It can run for both MySQL and PostGreSQL.

```
Post.select("Date(created_at) as date").order("date desc").uniq.limit(4)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what I want...but would it work with postgresql or it requires different syntax?

Comment: @AmrNoman, I have updated my answer, it will work as per your choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.order('created_at desc').select(:created_at).last(4)
```

Comment: Unfortunately if there were multiple posts created on the same day, this returns them all. I need only the unique dates. I think the problem is because "created_at" is a "datetime" attribute. should I create an additional "date" attribute? or is there another way?

Comment: You may use distinct clause : Post.order('created_at desc').select('distinct created_at').last(4)